# What is the equivalent US wage of £50,000 in the UK?

Tags: united-states, united-kingdom

If you're earning £50,000 per annum in the UK, you'll largely be considered very successful by most people. From my own personal experience the average range for most people is around £25-35k.

It seems that wages in the US are much much higher than in the UK. It's not uncommon to hear about people in the US earning $150k+ coming out of college. However it also seems that rent and other living expenses are also inflated, $1000-3000 rent per month in some places?

I'm curious as to what the equivalent of a £50k salary in the UK would be in US terms? I imagine it's very state dependent.

I'm not talking about exchange rate here though, rather the comparative cost of living between the two countries.

Comment: Bear in mind Americans don't get the NHS, but have to effectively self-insure their health. I'm digging up a very interesting blogpost I read about this...

Comment: `It's not uncommon to hear about people in the US earning $150k+ coming out of college` That absolutely is uncommon.

Comment: @AakashM: most non-small US employers, especially in higher-paying industries, pay all or most of health insurance premiums for employees and their families (although this insurance usually still requires some 'co-pay' or 'co-insurance' from the beneficiaries). Employers are mostly willing to do this because such payments are (generally) not subject to either FICA taxes or income tax, so it costs them less than equivalent cash pay. Almost all elderly or totally-disabled people, and most very poor ones, get government coverage (Medicare and Medicaid+SCHIP respectively).

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 and yet apparently [half a million Americans a year declare bankruptcy because of medical bills](https://www.nasdaq.com/article/medical-bankruptcy-is-killing-the-american-middle-class-cm1099561).

Comment: Also depends on region/city - in London it wouldn't be outstanding.

Comment: Depends *vastly* on region / city in both countries. https://www.numbeo.com/cost-of-living/compare_countries_result.jsp?country1=United+States&country2=United+Kingdom provides an overview and lets you narrow down to particular cities.

Comment: Depending on the field of study in college, average income for a new graduate would be in the 40k-60k range(in many technical or engineering fields).  Doing well in the US is probably $100k after 5-10 years of experience.  But the US is HUGE compared to the UK so cost of living/rent will vary vastly.  For example, I paid $650/mo for a two bedroom apartment in Michigan but you could easily pay $1500/mo for a similar apartment in a large city.

Comment: @Steve-o169 The regional disparities are wild, median 2-bed rent in a number of CA cities is ~$4,000/month.   https://www.apartmentlist.com/rentonomics/national-rent-data/

Comment: The US is more comparable to a continent such as the entirety of Europe than just the UK alone. You'll have to specify a state.

Comment: @quid it's not uncommon to hear about it ;) In the same way it's not uncommon to hear about someone winning the lottery.... happens often. It's winning the lottery that's rare.

Comment: Related: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/538/how-to-match-eu-income-to-us-salary/

Comment: It's not uncommon to hear about people making $150K or so out of college precisely because it IS uncommon, and therefore newsworthy.  Also, the people making that sort of money are likely at the top levels of STEM, where an internship at top tech companies can pay close to $100K/year (if extrapolated to full time).  But your typical liberal arts major will make nowhere close to that, and in some popular fields may be stuck in an unpaid internship.

Comment: The US does have [higher wages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_income#Median_equivalent_adult_income) than the UK after accounting for cost of living. France and Germany have higher for that matter.

Comment: @AakashM (sorry I misplaced the link): .5M is about .15% of US population, or about .2% of adults; https://www.thegazette.co.uk/insolvency/content/103500 says England and Wales had over .25% of adults insolvent, even with NHS covering all medical. Your US link at the bottom also estimates US 'uncovered' (your self-insured) as 29M out of more than 300M; that's a significant fraction but nowhere near all.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 "all or most of health insurance premiums for employees and their families" There are a lot of costs that are not covered by this that are by the NHS.  The lifetime maximums seem to me a particularly frightening and harmful concept.

Comment: @User65535: that's true, and why I included the weasel-wording, but it's also true that _many_ people self-pay only modest amounts, even when they need treatment.

Answer (score 4):

In the same way that income over there likely differs between London employers and employers in, say, Belfast, you have a huge spread of incomes in the US.

The increase in incomes seems to be fairly close on both sides, so if your median income is around 35,000 pounds, and US median income is around $50,000 you have someone making 50,000 pounds to be roughly equivalent to someone making $75,000.

Obviously this is more or less restricted to whichever job you're talking about and it also differs quite a bit depending on whether or not it's a well-known company or a small business with 5 employees.

So yes, software engineers, right out of college make more than $100k here if they get hired by a small number of companies (Google, Microsoft, Netflix, maybe Amazon?), otherwise you're likely looking at $50-60k. Also do note that these people likely have 6 figures in student loan debt.

Answer (score 3):

According to the UK HM Revenue & Customs department, the salary percentile of someone making 50k Pounds is 86. Comparing to the US, the 86th percentile would be around 125k Us dollars.

Comment: Hi,this could be a great answer if you could add some references to the sources of the data. Right now your US number is completely unsourced and the UK reference is fairly vague.